# How to store data from scrapy spider parse function with Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

```
class archiveorg_spider(scrapy.Spider):
    
    name = 'youtube_link_crawler'
    allowed_domains = ['archive.org']
    start_urls = crawl_target_2016_Q1 # this can be changed
    
    def parse(self, response):
        
        print("processing!!:"+response.url)
        youtube_links = response.xpath('/html//div[@class = "metadata-expandable-list row"]//dd[@class = " breaker-breaker"]/a/text()').extract()
        
        for ylink in youtube_links:
            scraped_info = {
                'modified_archive_url': response.url,
                'associated_youtube_link': ylink,
            }                        
            yield scraped_info
```

How can I store the "scraped_info" into a CSV file?
I am running this on Jupyter Notebook.

Also for some reason "scrapy crawl" does not work,
so I am crawling using "CrawlerProcess"

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy allows you to define an export file by using [the `FEEDS` settings](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html?highlight=feeds#feeds). Eg.

```
process = CrawlerProcess(settings={
    "FEEDS": {
        "items.csv": {"format": "csv"},
    },
})

process.crawl(MySpider)
process.start()
```

[More about Feed exports](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html?highlight=feeds#feed-exports)

[More about running Scrapy from a script](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script)